# How to process unsuccessful subcription upgrade with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am new to Stripe and I can't figure out how to handle the such situation:

- A client has an active subscription. It is paid for N days
- Before ending this subscription, the clients try to upgrade it to a more advanced
- Stripe tries to make a payment but it fails
- After several fails stripe cancels the subscription

Instead of this, I want to revert the subscription to the previous one, because there are still N paid days of the previous subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to restate your issue here to make sure we are on the same page and provide context for my answer

### Problem

- A customer attempts to update their subscription, which requires a new payment
- The update succeeds (the Subscription is upgraded) but the new payment fails.
- The subscription cancels after repeated failed payment attempts

### Solution

You can configure how a modified Subscription responds to a payment failure by changing the `payment_behavior` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-payment_behavior) when making the the [Update API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) request.  In your case you want to provide `pending_if_incomplete`.

This will only change the Subscription if payment succeeds.  You can read the overview [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/pending-updates) and get details about parameter restrictions and the lifecycle of pending updates [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/pending-updates-reference#supported-attributes)

Comment: Thank you! I think it is a proper solution for my case

Comment: What about updating Quantity?  If I pass `pending_if_incomplete` and I update only the Quantity in the Subscription, Stripe updates the Quantity after a payment failure. Is there a way of blocking Quantity updates on a payment failure?